# Download files newer than X days from SFTP server with WinSCP, skipping folders that do not contain any matching files

Tags: sftp, winscp

I am limited to PuTTY and WinSCP only.

I am trying to download log directories with log files. For example, I want to grab all `log_files` 6 days old or newer. `log_dir2` and `log_dir3` including the folders match the criteria, while `log_dir1` and its files does not.

```
DIR/log_dir1/log_files % older than 6 days
DIR/log_dir2/log_files % meets criteria
DIR/log_dir3/log_files % meets criteria
```

My problem is that while the `log_files` of `log_dir1` are not downloaded, the syntax I am currently using downloads the `log_dir1` folder. Normally, not a big deal, but we are talking hundreds of `log_dir` folders (all empty as the files are older than 6 days). For reasons beyond my control, I cannot move or archive these old log directories with their log files.

My question is simply, how do I change my syntax to ignore folders that are older than 6 days as well as files.

```
get -filemask="*>6D" /DIR/* C:\temp
```

I have tried several different combinations of parameters and I have read the support page about Directory Masks and Path Masks. I cannot get any of them working (version issue?). Can anyone explain their syntax better than the [help page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask). I will update tomorrow with the current version of WinSCP that I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Time constraint in WinSCP file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time) cannot be used for directories.

---

But you can [prevent WinSCP from creating the empty folders](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#emptysubfolder). Use [`-rawtransfersettings` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#rawtransfersettings) with [`ExcludeEmptyDirectories` setting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings#excludeemptydirectories).

```
get -rawtransfersettings ExcludeEmptyDirectories=1 -filemask="*>6D" /DIR/* C:\temp
```

---

*This is the original answer, before WinSCP supported `ExcludeEmptyDirectories`. It might still be useful as a basis for implementations that have even more specific constraints.*

You can implement this custom logic easily in [PowerShell script with a use of WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell):

```powershell
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "example.com"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "..."
}

$remotePath = "/remote/path"
$localPath = "C:\local\path"
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Enumerate files to download
$fileInfos =
    $session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        $remotePath, $Null, [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::AllDirectories) |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $limit }

foreach ($fileInfo in $fileInfos)
{
    $localFilePath =
        [WinSCP.RemotePath]::TranslateRemotePathToLocal(
            $fileInfo.FullName, $remotePath, $localPath)

    # If the corresponding local folder does not exist yet, create it
    $localFileDir = Split-Path -Parent $localFilePath
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $localFileDir))
    {
        Write-Host "Creating local directory $localFileDir..."
        New-Item $localFileDir -ItemType directory | Out-Null
    }

    Write-Host "Downloading file $($fileInfo.FullName)..."

    # Download file
    $sourcePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($fileInfo.FullName)
    $transferResult = $session.GetFiles($sourcePath, $localFilePath)

    # Did the download succeeded?
    if (!$transferResult.IsSuccess)
    {
        # Print error (but continue with other files)
        Write-Host ("Error downloading file ${remoteFilePath}: " +
            $transferResult.Failures[0].Message)
    }
}

$session.Dispose()

Write-Host "Done."
```

Run the script (`download.ps1`) like:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File download.ps1
```