# Only upload the latest folder to FTP (Local -> Remote)

Tags: ftp, winscp

I need to be able to upload a local folder (created daily) to a remote FTP everyday.

I’ve messed with WinSCP file masks (i.e. `put -filemask="*>=today" C:\local\ /`) and ran into issues where it would upload the latest folder (contained subfiles) but it would also upload the rest of the folders in the directory. (they were empty)  I then realized filemasks only works specifically for files, not folders.

I then came across this thread: [Download files newer than X days from SFTP server with WinSCP, skipping folders that do not contain any matching files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965395/download-files-newer-than-x-days-from-sftp-server-with-winscp-skipping-folders)

- User had the same issue except he was going Remote -> Local whereas I need the opposite, solution was to use PowerShell

Considering that thread is a couple years old, does WinSCP scripting now support such a feature? Unfortunately I’m a bit of a novice with PowerShell.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP does not support time constraints for folders.

But what has changed (since the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45965395/850848)) is that now you can [prevent WinSCP from creating the empty folders](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#emptysubfolder). Use [`-rawtransfersettings` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#rawtransfersettings) with [`ExcludeEmptyDirectories` setting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings#excludeemptydirectories).

```
put -rawtransfersettings ExcludeEmptyDirectories=1 -filemask="*>=today" C:\local\ /
```

---

If you really need to upload the latest folder (as opposite to uploading the folder with the latest files), using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) from your favourite language (like [PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell)) is still the way to go, as shown in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45965395/850848).