# "Missing parameter for command 'get'" when downloading files within date range using WinSCP

Tags: ftp, winscp

I am using below command to download files from FTP but I am getting error

```
    "get -filemask="*>=2018-12-01" -preservetime -resume -speed=5000 /ECC/PITR/WAL_ARCHIVE E:\ECC\PITR\WAL_ARCHIVE\" ^
    "exit"
```

Error:

> > 2020-12-17 12:46:50.392 Script: get -filemask=*
> < 2020-12-17 12:46:50.392 Script: Missing parameter for command 'get'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the connection open before calling get?

https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11089

..."Script: Missing parameter for command 'get'."...

martin:

```
winscp.exe /console /command "option batch abort" "open root:password@192.168.1.11/private/var/root/folder1/" "get file1 c:\Users\me\Desktop\folder2"
```

Comment: Yes.. connection opened below is the log  2020-12-17 12:46:50.392 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2020-12-17 12:46:50.392 Script: Active session: [1] ****/support@****.com@*****.sharefileftp.com
> 2020-12-17 12:46:50.392 Script: get -filemask=*
< 2020-12-17 12:46:50.392 Script: Missing parameter for command 'get'.
. 2020-12-17 12:46:50.392 Script: Failed

Answer (score 0):

You have the quotes wrong.

Either [double the inner quotes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax):

```
    "get -filemask=""*>=2018-12-01"" -preservetime -resume -speed=5000 /ECC/PITR/WAL_ARCHIVE E:\ECC\PITR\WAL_ARCHIVE\" ^
```

Or as the quotes around the file mask are redundant, as there's no space in the mask, you can remove them altogether:

```
    "get -filemask=*>=2018-12-01 -preservetime -resume -speed=5000 /ECC/PITR/WAL_ARCHIVE E:\ECC\PITR\WAL_ARCHIVE\" ^
```

See also [Why are some WinSCP scripting commands specified in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)

---

If you want to avoid downloading folders, that do not contain any relevant files, see [Download files newer than X days from SFTP server with WinSCP, skipping folders that do not contain any matching files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45965395/850848).