# Download one day old files from all FTP directories to one local directory using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

Goal:  I'm trying to get all files that are 1 day old or newer.  The remote directory has a lot of directories as well as files on the root directory.

I need to look in each directory, get any files 1 day old, as well as any file on the root directory 1 day old, and transfer all of those to 1 single directory. I'd like to not copy any empty directories, or any directories with files older than 1 day old.

The current code just keeps running and doesn't transfer any files.  I'm not sure if I set up the `foreach` correctly, as well as the `GetFiles` section.

What does the `GetFiles` section need to say to meet the file requirements listed above?

Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Code:

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol              = [WinSCP.Protocol]::ftp
    HostName              = "ftp site"
    UserName              = "UserName"
    Password              = "Password"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "stuff"
}

$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("FSProtocol", "2")

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.SessionLogPath = $log
try {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Set up transfer options
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions -Property @{
        TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Ascii
    }
    $lcdPath = 'Filepath\'
    $time = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)   
    $files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $lcdPath -Attributes !Directory -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $time })    
    
    # Transfer files
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $session.GetFiles($files, "LocalFilePath", $False, $transferOptions).Check()
    }
}
finally {
    $session.Dispose()
}
exit 0
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's example of WinSCP site that implements part of what you want to achieve:
[Downloading all files from FTP/SFTP to the same local folder](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_files_to_same_folder).

You just need to add the time condition, for which you can check:
[Download files newer than X days from SFTP server with WinSCP, skipping folders that do not contain any matching files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45965395/850848)

Combining those together, this should do:

```
$remotePath = "/remote/path"
$localPath = "C:\local\path"
$mask = "*.txt"
 
$files = $session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
             $remotePath, $mask, [WinSCP.EnumerationOptions]::AllDirectories)
 
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$files = $files | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $limit }

foreach ($fileInfo in $files)
{
    Write-Host "Downloading $($fileInfo.FullName) ..."
    $session.GetFileToDirectory($fileInfo.FullName, $localPath) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues, and your code will require some re-working but your close.

Your biggest issue is your looking for new files in `Filepath\` in the current directory on your local file system, not on the FTP server:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $lcdPath -Attributes !Directory -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $time })
```

I think you want to [list the remote files on the FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) and build your `$files` list from this data instead. (example below taken from winscp.net)

```
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)
 
        $directory = $session.ListDirectory("/home/martin/public_html")
 
        foreach ($fileInfo in $directory.Files)
        {
            Write-Host ("$($fileInfo.Name) with size $($fileInfo.Length), " +
                "permissions $($fileInfo.FilePermissions) and " +
                "last modification at $($fileInfo.LastWriteTime)")
        }
```

You can adapt this code to populate your `$files` array based on `$fileinfo.LastWriteTime` of the remote files, then pass this to your "Transfer files" foreach loop.

Also you have some syntax problems with your try/catch/finally code, it should look like this:

```
catch
{
  Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
  exit 1
}
finally {
  $session.Dispose()
}
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you @MisterSmith!  I am grateful for your help!   I corrected my catch and I'm pulling back files with the code you helped me with!  I need to modify it to only pull back files with size greater than 0 and only modified for the last 1 day.  

Should I filter for that in the ForEach statement itself or inside the ForEach?  I just need to grab only files recursively from the root.

I changed one part of the code to pull from the root of the FTP site:   $directory = $session.ListDirectory("/")

Comment: Also, I appreciate the help on the logic flaw of looking on a local directory instead of the FTP directory.

Comment: ListDirectory will only list the contents of the specified directory. You can do a recursive search with `Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles` instead. I would suggest you define before the foreach loop `$files = @()` (an empty array), then inside the foreach you can test each file to confirm the `LastWriteTime`, `Length` etc match your criteria and append the remote path to your `$files` array.  Take a look at the examples listed here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles#real-life_examples

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  I couldn't get Session.enumerateRemoteFiles to work, so I chose a different path, I'll put it in as an answer in case it's helpful to others.