# Get files only 1 day old, not directories, using file mask in WinSCP

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp

I want to download all files 1 day old, regardless if they are in a directory, subdirectory, or on the root directory. Typically there is a list of directories with old files and a new file will be placed in the old directory every now and then.

The code below pulls the entire directory when it has at least one, 1-day old file has been placed in it.  I'd like to only pull the 1-day old files from the directories and not the entire directory when a new file is placed in it.

Is this possible with a filemask?  If so, what would I need to change below in the sample PowerShell code?  (The log and destination variables are built prior to this script.)

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" `
    /log="$log" /ini=nul `
    /command `
    "open ftpsite / -hostkey=`"`"hostKeyInfo`"`" -rawsettings FSProtocol=2" `
    "cd /" `
    "lcd $path" `
    "get -FileMask *>=1D" `
    "exit"
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are missing a `=` after the `-filemask`.
- You might want to add `-rawtransfersettings ExcludeEmptyDirectories=on` to skip the folders that do not contain any eligible files.

Complete command should be like this:

```
get -filemask=*>=1D -rawtransfersettings ExcludeEmptyDirectories=on *
```

See also [Download files newer than X days from SFTP server with WinSCP, skipping folders that do not contain any matching files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45965395/850848)